# Undefined references to 'get_rome_version' and 'rome_download' when compiling 'btusb_probe' in SM-G360T kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make, gcc, android

When I try to compile the kernel for the Samsung SM-G360T / SM-G360T1, I get identical issues for two different source repositories of the kernel.

Kernels I am using:
https://github.com/MSM8916-Samsung/android_kernel_samsung_coreprimeltexx (Should be stock)
https://github.com/ShinySide/SM-G360T1_kernel (Heavily Edited)

The first issue, referenced [here](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/issues/366), was solved with the replacement of one line of code.

in `btusb.c`:

```
static int reset = 1;
```

becomes

```
static bool reset = true;
```

I am including this just for reference in case it has something to do with the end result, or someone else comes along a similar issue. There is not a lot of documentation for this specific phone model's kernel, whereas it is a very popular model. [Here](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/issues/467) is listed another solution fort this issue that i did not try to use.

That part is solved. For the actual problem:

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `btusb_probe':
/android_kernel_samsung_coreprimeltexx/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:1368: 
undefined reference to `get_rome_version'
/android_kernel_samsung_coreprimeltexx/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:1373: 
undefined reference to `rome_download'
/android_kernel_samsung_coreprimeltexx/Makefile:807: recipe for target 
'vmlinux' failed
make[1]: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

I'm sure that this will be flagged as a repeat question, but It looks like `rome_download` and `get_rome_version` are defined (or at least referenced, forgive me, i'm bad) in `include/net/bluetooth/bluetooth.h` and `drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.c`.

If i comment out a few line edit a statement i can get the code to compile without the `version` variable which is called by the `btusb_probe` function. Obviously this is breaking some sort of functionality, but it seems to work.

Thanks for the help in advance. I was a little more long-winded than normal because this specific model of the device has uniquely limited information/development compared to the other versions of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while ago, but for all who need it: also enable CONFIG_BT_ATH3K in kernel. "Atheros firmware download driver" in
-> Networking support (NET [=y])
-> Bluetooth subsystem support (BT [=y])
-> Bluetooth device drivers